# Charging and then using that token to create customer

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, stripe-payments

I have a react native application that allows the user to add a payment method and then make payments using that payment method. My problem is: when the user adds a payment method (using tipsi-stripe card form), the token generated is then used to charge the user with some amount, which successfully happens. That same token is then used to generate a customer (using `stripe.customers.create()`) . This throws the following error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: You cannot use a Stripe token more than once: tok_**********************.`.

Is there a better way to do this without asking the user for their card details more than once?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Save the card to a Customer first, then Charge that Customer. https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards

Comment: So first create the customer then instead of using token to charge the user, use the customer-id and then save that customer id. Sounds pretty straightforward. I feel so stupid now! Thanks a ton @duck!

Comment: Yep, exactly :)